# How to install cocos 2d-x in visual studio, in window 8 operating system

Tags: visual-c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

**How to install cocos2dx templates in VS2010 and  how to create new cocos2dx project .**

I am installing cocos2d-x when i am import(cocos2d-win32.vc2010.sln) in VS2010 then whole cocos2dx are imported in VS2010 and it compile successfully also . but when i try to create new project my in cocos2dx. i go to vs2010.

> FILE-NEW-CREATE NEW PROJECT

but in my VS cocos2dx templates are not installed.

how to set environmental variable for python ?.

i follow this link-http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Setup_win32_development_environment.
i am not able to follow set-4 in this tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Before cocos2d-x 2.1.2, you can still use templates in VS. However, you can only use python to  create project

1. Install python 2.7
2. Open command line in Windows
3. Go to your cocos2d-x-2.1.5\tools\project-creator folder
4. Run create_project.py. Usage:

> create_project.py -project YourProjectName -package com.example.PakcageName -language cpp

-language option:[cpp | lua | javascript]

Your project will be created in cocos2d-x-2.1.5\projects

Then find the `win32.proj` , open ***.sln