# How to install cocos2d-x in windows8 and VS2013

Tags: cocos2d-x

I want to install cocos2d-x on my windows8 but i download this "http://bit.ly/18xmkJ9" from "http://cocos2d-x.org/download" in the tutorial says that i must execute a .bat in there or in some other pages says that i neet to create a project in VS, but when i try to do what they say in the tutorial i dont see anithing that is shown.

I'm very lost and help needed.

Could anybody say me hoy to createand start a project on cocos2d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answer the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381634/how-to-install-cocos-2d-x-in-visual-studio-in-window-8-operating-system/19853437#19853437).

Before cocos2d-x 2.1.2, you can still use templates in VS. However, you can only use python to  create project

1. Install python 2.7
2. Open command line in Windows
3. Go to your cocos2d-x-2.1.5\tools\project-creator folder
4. Run create_project.py. Usage:

> create_project.py -project YourProjectName -package com.example.PakcageName -language cpp

-language option:[cpp | lua | javascript]

Your project will be created in cocos2d-x-2.1.5\projects

Then find the `win32.proj` , open ***.sln