# How to create a new Android project with Cocos2d-x

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I'm a newbie in Cocos2d-x. I read instruction to build samples and did successfully. However, I want to create my own project which can be able to run on Android. Can you give me a detail tutorial such as how to create project, how to implement classes, resources, etc.

In addition,I'm developing in Windows 7, so I can't setup X-Code like this tutorial. Are there any other solutions?

http://www.raywenderlich.com/33752/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-space-game

Thank you so much

Comment: Refer to http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_set_up_the_android_cocos2d-x_development_environment_on_Windows_7

Comment: @Ivan: I read it many times. If I use their samples to build, it's totally ok. But I want to create my own project. How can I do? They say run create_project.py. I did, too but what's next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answer the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381634/how-to-install-cocos-2d-x-in-visual-studio-in-window-8-operating-system/19853437#19853437).

Following step can create multi-platform project,include Android:

1. Install python 2.7
2. Open command line in Windows
3. Go to your cocos2d-x-2.1.5\tools\project-creator folder
4. Run create_project.py. Usage:

> create_project.py -project YourProjectName -package com.example.PakcageName -language cpp

-language option:[cpp | lua | javascript]

Your project will be created in cocos2d-x-2.1.5\projects

Then find the `proj.android` , and import into Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

you can check this useful link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/802626/Writing-Games-with-Cplusplus-for-Android-on-a-PC-S

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It includes these steps:

1. Create new project by using create_project.py in ../tools/creator/
2. Import the the new project to Eclipse
3. Start to modify classes in Classes folder and change resource in Resources folder. They are all in NewProject folder.

At this time, I just develop by Notepad++ and use Eclipse to build. I'm finding a way to debug.